# How to convert the perl index script to bash function

Tags: bash, perl, ubuntu, indexof

I want to use `perl` to get the `index of` from `any given string` and `substring` in bash function.

**Here is the example for getting the indexOf value from perl script:**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-index-function/

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 
# String from which Substring 
# is to be searched 
$string = "Geeks are the best";
 
# Using index() to search for substring
$index = index ($string, 'the');
 
# Printing the position of the substring
print "Position of 'the' in the string: $index\n";

Output:

Position of 'the' in the string: 10
```

**Here is the test.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

bash_function_get_index_from_perl_script() {
    local index="-1"
    
    # Here is the dummy code 
    # as I don't know how to convert
    # the perl script to bash command lines
    # and get the result from perl script
    
    index="
    
        #!/usr/bin/perl
         
        # String from which Substring 
        # is to be searched 
        $string = "Geeks are the best";
         
        # Using index() to search for substring
        $index = index ($string, 'the');
         
        # Printing the position of the substring
        print "Position of 'the' in the string: $index\n";
    
    "
    
    printf "%s" "$index"
}

result="$(bash_function_get_index_from_perl_script)"

echo "result is: $result"
```

**Here is the expected output:**

```
result is: 10
```

How to implement the "`bash_function_get_index_from_perl_script`"?

**Update:**

**Here is the bash function for testing:**

```
#!/bin/bash

bash_function_get_index() {
    local string="$1"
    local search_string="$2"
    
    before=${string%${search_string}*}
    index=${#before}
    
    printf "%s" "$index"
}

echo "test 1: $(bash_function_get_index "hello world" "wo")"
echo "test 2: $(bash_function_get_index "hello world" "wox")"
```

Here is the output:

```
test 1: 6
test 2: 11
```

The result of "test 2" is wrong, it should be:

```
test 2: -1
```

**I want to implement the same "indexOf" function from Java:**

https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_indexof.asp

```
index_of() {
    local string="$1"
    local search_string="$2"
    local fromIndex="$3"
    
    local index=""
    
    # Get the real index here, the result shoule be the same as the Java's "indexOf"
        
    printf "%s" "$index"
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

**Here is a testing based on the "`@F. Hauri - Give Up GitHub`"'s solution:**

The following `test_example` is used to get the "`inner code`" between "`if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_111111)) {`" and "`}`".

I used a second variable "`hello_world`" to get a `from_index` for getting the real index of "}".

**But the  "`test_example`" is not working as expected. It seems the "`indexOf()`" function is not working as expected.**

```
#!/bin/bash

indexOf() {
    if [[ $1 == -v ]]; then
        local -n _iO_result="$2"
        shift 2
    else
        local _iO_result
    fi
    local _iO_string="$2" _iO_substr="$1" _iO_lhs
    _iO_lhs=${_iO_string%"$_iO_substr"*}
    _iO_result=${#_iO_lhs}
    ((_iO_result == ${#_iO_string} )) && _iO_result=-1
    case ${_iO_result@A} in _iO_result=* ) echo $_iO_result;;esac
}

indexOf_my_params() {
    local string="$1"
    local search_string="$2"
    local from_index="$3"
    
    local offset=-1
    
    if [[ "$from_index" == "" ]]
    then
        offset=0
    else
        if (( $from_index < 0 ))
        then
            from_index=0
        fi
        
        local count=$((${#string} - $from_index))
        if (( $count >= 0 ))
        then
            offset=$from_index
            string="${string:from_index:count}"
        fi
    fi
    
    local index=-1
    
    if [[ "$offset" != "-1" ]]
    then
        index="$(indexOf "$search_string" "$string")"
        
        if (( $index != -1 ))
        then
            index=$(($index + $offset))
        fi
    fi
    
    printf '%s' "$index"
    return "$((index < 0))"
}

test_example() {
    local content="$(cat <<END
initialize(args, hw);
if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_111111)) {
    args.add("foo");
    if(1>2) {
        args.add("test");
    }else{
        args.add("x");
    }
    args.add("hello world");
}

if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_222222)) {
    args.add("bar");
}
END
        )"
        
        local feature_1_if_begin="if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_111111)) {"
        local hello_world="args.add(\"hello world\");"
        local feature_1_if_end="}"
        
        local feature_1_if_begin_index="$(indexOf_my_params "$content" "$feature_1_if_begin")"
        echo "feature_1_if_begin_index: $feature_1_if_begin_index"
        
        local hello_world_index="$(indexOf_my_params "$content" "$hello_world" "$(($feature_1_if_begin_index + ${#feature_1_if_begin}))")"
        echo "hello_world_index: $hello_world_index"
        
        local feature_1_if_end_index="$(indexOf_my_params "$content" "$feature_1_if_end" "$(($hello_world_index + ${#hello_world}))")"
        echo "feature_1_if_end_index: $feature_1_if_end_index"
        
        local feature_1_if_block_code="${content:$(($feature_1_if_begin_index + ${#feature_1_if_begin})):$(($feature_1_if_end_index - $feature_1_if_begin_index - ${#feature_1_if_begin}))}"
        
        echo "------ feature_1_if_block_code (inner code) ------"
        printf "%s\n" "$feature_1_if_block_code"
        
}

test_example
exit 0
```

**Here is the actual output (the output is wrong):**

```
feature_1_if_begin_index: 22
hello_world_index: 169
feature_1_if_end_index: 260
------ feature_1_if_block_code (inner code) ------

    args.add("foo");
    if(1>2) {
        args.add("test");
    }else{
        args.add("x");
    }
    args.add("hello world");
}

if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_222222)) {
    args.add("bar");
```

**Here is the expected output:**

```
------ feature_1_if_block_code (inner code) ------

    args.add("foo");
    if(1>2) {
        args.add("test");
    }else{
        args.add("x");
    }
    args.add("hello world");
```

Why is the "`indexOf()`" not working when the `search keyword` is "`}`"?

**UPDATE 3 (use the same "content" for testing as UPDATE 2):**

Here is a solution from Paul Hodges but still not working as expected:
Note that I renamed the function name "`index`" to "`indexof_paul_hodges`".

```
#!/bin/bash

indexof_paul_hodges ()
{
    local string="$1" key="$2" fromIndex=${3:-0};
    (( fromIndex )) && string=${string:$fromIndex};
    if [[ "$string" =~ "$key" ]]; then
        local ndx="${string%%"$key"*}";
        echo ${#ndx};
    else
        echo "-1";
    fi
}

test_example() {
    local content="$(cat <<END
initialize(args, hw);
if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_111111)) {
    args.add("foo");
    if(1>2) {
        args.add("test");
    }else{
        args.add("x");
    }
    args.add("hello world");
}

if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_222222)) {
    args.add("bar");
}
END
        )"
        
        local feature_1_if_begin="if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_111111)) {"
        local hello_world="args.add(\"hello world\");"
        local feature_1_if_end="}"
        
        local feature_1_if_begin_index="$(indexof_paul_hodges "$content" "$feature_1_if_begin")"
        echo "feature_1_if_begin_index: $feature_1_if_begin_index"
        
        local hello_world_index="$(indexof_paul_hodges "$content" "$hello_world" "$(($feature_1_if_begin_index + ${#feature_1_if_begin}))")"
        echo "hello_world_index: $hello_world_index"
        
        local feature_1_if_end_index="$(indexof_paul_hodges "$content" "$feature_1_if_end" "$(($hello_world_index + ${#hello_world}))")"
        echo "feature_1_if_end_index: $feature_1_if_end_index"
        
        local feature_1_if_block_code="${content:$(($feature_1_if_begin_index + ${#feature_1_if_begin})):$(($feature_1_if_end_index - $feature_1_if_begin_index - ${#feature_1_if_begin}))}"
        
        echo "------ feature_1_if_block_code (inner code) ------"
        printf "%s\n" "$feature_1_if_block_code"
        
}

test_example
exit 0
```

**Here is the output of "`indexof_paul_hodges`" (The result is wrong):**

```
feature_1_if_begin_index: 22
hello_world_index: 106
feature_1_if_end_index: 33
------ feature_1_if_block_code (inner code) ------

    args.add("foo");
    if(1>2) {
        args.add("test");
    }else{
        args.add("x");
    }
    args.add("hello world");
}

if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_222
```

**UPDATE 4 (Use the same `test_example()` of `UPDATE 2` for testing):**

Here is a solution from @choroba:

```
#!/bin/bash

bash_function_get_index() {
    local string=$1
    local search=$2
    [[ $string = *"$search"* ]] || { printf %s -1 ; return ; }
    local before=${string%%"$search"*}
    local index=${#before}
    printf %s "$index"
}

indexOf_my_params() {
    local string="$1"
    local search_string="$2"
    local from_index="$3"
    
    local offset=-1
    
    if [[ "$from_index" == "" ]]
    then
        offset=0
    else
        if (( $from_index < 0 ))
        then
            from_index=0
        fi
        
        local count=$((${#string} - $from_index))
        if (( $count >= 0 ))
        then
            offset=$from_index
            string="${string:from_index:count}"
        fi
    fi
    
    local index=-1
    
    if [[ "$offset" != "-1" ]]
    then
        index="$(bash_function_get_index "$string" "$search_string")"
        
        if (( $index != -1 ))
        then
            index=$(($index + $offset))
        fi
    fi
    
    printf '%s' "$index"
    return "$((index < 0))"
}
```

**Here is the output of UPDATE 4 (The result is correct)**

```
feature_1_if_begin_index: 22
hello_world_index: 169
feature_1_if_end_index: 194
------ feature_1_if_block_code (inner code) ------

    args.add("foo");
    if(1>2) {
        args.add("test");
    }else{
        args.add("x");
    }
    args.add("hello world");
```

Comment: `before=${string%${search_string}*}` should be `before=${string%"${search_string}"*}` otherwise it may fail in some edge cases. eg. when `search_string` contains glob characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways. For example, you can send the script to the standard input of perl:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

bash_function_get_index_from_perl_script() {
    index=$(perl <<- '_PERL_'
    $string = 'Geeks are the best';
    $index = index $string, 'the';
    print "Position of 'the' in the string: $index\n";
    _PERL_
    )
    printf "%s" "$index"
}

result=$(bash_function_get_index_from_perl_script)

echo "result is: $result"
```

But you don't need Perl for that, you can find the position using parameter expansion in bash itself:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

bash_function_get_index() {
    string=$1
    search=$2
    [[ $string = *"$search"* ]] || { printf %s -1 ; return ; }
    before=${string%%"$search"*}
    index=${#before}
    printf %s "$index"
}

for s in the thex ; do
    result=$(bash_function_get_index 'Geeks are the best' "$s")
    echo "Position of '$s' in the string: $result"
done
```

To include a start position, just remove everything before the start position from the string before trying to match the substring. Don't forget to add the start position to the result:

```bash
bash_function_get_index() {
    string=$1
    search=$2
    pos=${3:-0}
    string=${string:$pos}
    [[ $string = *"$search"* ]] || { printf %s -1 ; return ; }
    before=${string%%"$search"*}
    index=${#before}
    printf %s $(( pos + index ))
}
```

Comment: I tested your "`bash_function_get_index`" and found a problem, the result is incorrect. Please see my updated post in the "`update`" section.

Comment: You've changed the question substantially. The only problem is there's no check for the case where the substring doesn't exist (since the original question didn't have any arguments). A simple `[[ $string = *"$search"* ]] || { printf %s -1 ; return ; }` should fix that.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `%%` to make sure you picked up the first match?

Comment: @PaulHodges: You're right, thanks. Updated.

Comment: Hi, @choroba, Thank you so much, I tested your soluction in "`UPDATE 4`", and the result is correct. Can you help to add a "`from_index`" argument into your "`bash_function_get_index`" as my original "`indexOf_my_params`" has a little complex.

Comment: I tested the `bash_function_get_index` in my other bash scripts with complex content, the result is correct. I will accept this as an answer. It's better if the `bash_function_get_index` has a "`from_index`" argument.

Comment: @choroba or `case $string in *$search* ) ... ;; esac` which is a little quicker!

Comment: @stackbiz: Start position solution added.

Answer (score 1):

#### Index Of *substring* in *string* in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

Try this:

```bash
string="Geeks are the best"
sub=the
lhs=${string%"$sub"*}
echo ${#lhs}
10
```

#### As a function

with `-v` option to assign a variable instead of echoing. In order to avoid useless forks:

```bash
indexOf() {
    if [[ $1 == -v ]]; then
        local -n _iO_result="$2"
        shift 2
    else
        local _iO_result
    fi
    local _iO_string="$2" _iO_substr="$1" _iO_lhs
    _iO_lhs=${_iO_string%"$_iO_substr"*}
    _iO_result=${#_iO_lhs}
    ((_iO_result == ${#_iO_string} )) && _iO_result=-1
    case ${_iO_result@A} in _iO_result=* ) echo "$_iO_result";;esac
}
```

With an exeption: if *substring* not found, then answer is `-1`.

#### Tests and syntax

Then

```bash
indexOf the "Geeks are the best"
10

indexOf -v var the "Geeks are the best"
echo $var
10

indexOf bad "Hello good world!"
-1

indexOf '*' 'abc*efg???x'
3
```

Then for avoiding forks `var=$(function...)`, use `-v var` option!!

```bash
tcnt=1;for tests in  $'wo\thello world' $'wox\thello world' $'*\tabc*efg???x'; do
    tststr=${tests%%$'\t'*} string=${tests#*$'\t'}
    indexOf -v idx "$tststr" "$string"
    printf 'Test %2d: result: %3d. string "%s" substring: "%s"\n' \
        $((tcnt++)) "$idx" "$string" "$tststr"
done
```

should produce:

```
Test  1: result:   6. string "hello world" substring: "wo"
Test  2: result:  -1. string "hello world" substring: "wox"
Test  3: result:   3. string "abc*efg???x" substring: "*"
```

#### Why do I insist about *avoiding forks*

Just try to run 1'000 time the job:

```bash
time for ((i=1000;i--;)){ idx=$(indexOf 'wo' 'Hello world') ;};echo $idx
```

```
real    0m0.948s
user    0m0.608s
sys     0m0.337s
6
```

```bash
time for ((i=1000;i--;)){ indexOf -v idx 'wo' 'Hello world' ;};echo $idx
```

```
real    0m0.030s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.000s
6
```

From approx 1 seconds to approx 3 100th of second!!

No comment!

Comment: Is it possible for implementing the "'`fromIndex'`" in the same "`'indexOf'`" function? It is very useful with "`fromIndex`".

Comment: @stackbiz I think you have to ask another question. But extracting a substring from a positional argument, try: `echo ${string:2:3}` for echoing 3 character form the 2nd of `$string`

Comment: I'm trying your solution in my bash scripts, I will accept answer later after testing without problem.

Comment: After doing some testing, the result is:  `the "indexOf()" not working when the search keyword is "}".` Please see the "`UPDATE 2`" section in my post.

Comment: @stackbiz `string='if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_111111)) {" and "';indexOf '{' "$string"` give `40` This work fine!

Comment: Can you help to check the variable of "`local feature_1_if_block_code`" in my "`test_example`"? It is used the same "`indexOf()`" function but I can't figure out why the result is not working.

Comment: Note the "`indexOf_my_params`" is a wrapper of "`indexOf()`" in my "`test_example`", I just added a "fromIndex" argument for getting the substring before doing the "indexOf()"

Comment: Instead of `index="$(indexOf "$search_string" "$string")"` use `indexOf -v index "$search_string" "$string"` , please!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is doing anything dramatically different from what others have done, but implements what you've asked for with native built-in bash-isms and is maybe a little easier to read?

```
$: declare -f index
index ()
{
    local string="$1" key="$2" fromIndex=${3:-0};
    (( fromIndex )) && string=${string:$fromIndex};
    if [[ "$string" =~ "$key" ]]; then
        local ndx="${string%%"$key"*}";
        echo ${#ndx};
    else
        echo "-1";
    fi
}

$: index "Geeks are the best" the
10

$: index "Geeks are the best" the 4
6

$: index "Geeks are the best" the 12
-1

$: index "Geeks are the best" foo
-1
```

---

## Edit

This smacks of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) with a horribly fragile Y. What is it that you are actually trying to accomplish?

In general, unless you are ABSOLUTELY in COMPLETE and SOLE control of the code (and probably not even then), don't try to parse code this way. One small "harmless" change now breaks your parse.

Even so, your problem is that you are using offsets for reference that aren't counting from the same place. You have to index from the start of your source string, even if you had to use a point in the middle to identify the correct closing brace...which is what makes this so fragile.

```bash
$: cat tst
#!/bin/bash
indexof_paul_hodges () { local string="$1" key="$2" fromIndex=${3:-0};
    (( fromIndex )) && string=${string:$fromIndex};
    if [[ "$string" =~ "$key" ]]
    then local ndx="${string%%"$key"*}";
         echo ${#ndx};
    else echo "-1"; # this should probably be "return 1"
    fi
}
test_example() { local content="$1"
  local -i if_begin_index if_begin_end hello_world_index hello_world_end if_end_index
  local if_begin=$'if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_111111)) {' hello_world=$'args.add("hello world");' if_end="}"
  if_begin_index="$(indexof_paul_hodges "$content" "$if_begin")"
  if_begin_end=if_begin_index+${#if_begin}
  hello_world_index="$( indexof_paul_hodges "$content" "$hello_world" )"                      # index FROM START
  hello_world_end=hello_world_index+${#hello_world}
  if_end_index=$(indexof_paul_hodges "$content" "$if_end" "$hello_world_end")+hello_world_end # index FROM START
  local if_block="${content:$if_begin_index:$if_end_index - $if_begin_index + 1}"             # include all
  local if_content="${content:$if_begin_end:$if_end_index - $if_begin_end}"                   # inside braces only
  printf "%s\n" "--- if block ---" "$if_block" "" "--- inner code ---"  "$if_content"
}
content='
    initialize(args, hw);
    if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_111111)) { /* comments can show up anywhere */
      if(1>2) { args.add("test"); } else { args.add("x"); }
      args.add("hello world"); /* comments can include braces... */
    }
    if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_222222)) { args.add("bar"); }
  '
echo "As-is:";                 test_example "$content"
echo "with a comment edited:"; test_example "${content/braces/\}}"
```

when run:

```
$: ./tst
As-is:
--- if block ---
if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_111111)) { /* comments can show up anywhere */
      if(1>2) { args.add("test"); } else { args.add("x"); }
      args.add("hello world"); /* comments can include braces... */
    }

--- inner code ---
 /* comments can show up anywhere */
      if(1>2) { args.add("test"); } else { args.add("x"); }
      args.add("hello world"); /* comments can include braces... */

with a comment edited:
--- if block ---
if (feature_is_enabled(Feature_111111)) { /* comments can show up anywhere */
      if(1>2) { args.add("test"); } else { args.add("x"); }
      args.add("hello world"); /* comments can include }

--- inner code ---
 /* comments can show up anywhere */
      if(1>2) { args.add("test"); } else { args.add("x"); }
      args.add("hello world"); /* comments can include
```

So again: What is it that you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your `index()` function is still not working as expected, please see my updated post section: `UPDATE 3 (use the same "content" for testing as UPDATE 2):`

Comment: The function works; you are setting `feature_1_if_end_index="$(indexof_paul_hodges "$content" "$feature_1_if_end" "$(($hello_world_index + ${#hello_world}))")"` which is losing the characters up to the end of `$hello_world`. You have to add those back in. See my update above, at `if_end_index=$(indexof_paul_hodges "$content" "$if_end" "$hello_world_end")+hello_world_end`

Comment: My original `feature_1_if_end_index="$(indexof_paul_hodges "$content" "$feature_1_if_end" "$(($hello_world_index + ${#hello_world}))")"` is correct. Your `index()` only work on some cases but not working on my original `test_example()`.